# Secure Random in Login Process

Tags: java, hash, sha, javax.crypto

I have been trying to do some Password verification module, I got stuck up in verification process. I create Salt bytes by Secure Random. And stored it in database in *BINARY* format.

```
random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
random.nextBytes(salt);
```

I hashed my password using

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(charData,salt,iterations,bitLength);
hash = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec).getEncoded();
```

When I tried to verify the Password (i.e. Generating hash using the salt value from db). I'm not getting same hash value. Is there something i'm doing wrong.

Comment: First verify that the bytes in the `salt` that you generate are identical to the ones you retrieve from the database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is storing data in *BINARY* format. It will take the actual data and append *0's* at the end to fill up the remaining bytes. So if you don't know the actual size of the binary data use **BLOB** Datatype it will store only the actual data.